# Angularjs Data Binding among Controller, Directive, and Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to update content of a directive with the data coming from a service. It works like this:

1. Service (html5 canvas service) -> calls a method in controller on some action
2. Controller updates $scope.directiveData inside the method called by service
3. Directive (scope: true) should update its content according to the new data

The problem is directive does not update its content. However, when I add a periodic update to directiveData in the controller:

```
$interval(function() {$scope.directiveData.abc;}, 100);
```

Directive updates its content!

Is there any explanation for this behavior? How can I get rid of this periodic update?

I simulated the problem in jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eyNYw/857/

Answer (score 1):

`scope: true` makes directive scope isolated ([Angular directive. Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)). So this directive doesn't see controller variable $scope.directiveData.

You can add isolated variable like this

```
scope: {directiveData: '='}
```

> '=' - means two way binding

And then pass $scope.directiveData through the directive attributes

```
<your-directive directive-data="directiveData"></your-directive>
```

When you update $scope.directiveData angular will update this one for directive.

Comment: I tried this one and scope: false, which does not isolate scope at all. Same behavior. I think it is not only about data binding between controller-directive. It is also about service that is calling a function from controller.

Comment: Need more details. At least example of controller action and directive code.